# Variable in controller is lost when passing between views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I am currently stuck with an issue in my MVC 4 application. I have private variable in controller, that holds instance of a simple class:

```
 private InstallationStatus status = null;
```

When data get submitted on a view, it gets filled like this:

```
InstallationStatus installStatus = Install();
if (installStatus != null)
{
    status = installStatus;
    TempData["installPercent"] = 0;
    return View("InstallationProgress", status);
}
```

This part works as intended, variable is set to the instance as it should be.

After that view periodically checks another variable (using ajax):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var progress = 0;
        $("div.status-message").text("Progress: " + progress + "%");
        var statusUpdate = setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "/AppStart/GetInstallProgress",
                datatype: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    progress = parseInt(data);
                    if (progress >= 100) {
                        clearInterval(statusUpdate);
                        var data = $(this).serialize();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: "@Url.Action("CompletedStatus", "AppStart")",
                            success: function () {
                                window.location = "/Login/Login"
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    $("div.status-message").text("Progress: " + progress + "%");
                }
            });


        }, 2000);
        });
</script>
```

When it calls "CompletedStatus" action on the controller, variable "status" on the controller is null (the instance set previously is not there?

How do I ensure that its value will persist? It seems to me like whole instance of controller gets lost, but that doesnt really matter to me - the source for "status" is webservice and once I get the instance of InstallationStatus, I cant get it again - I need to keep it.

I tried using TempData to store it but since there can be more than one step between storing it and retrieving it TempData proved unreliable.

The final process is:

1. Request installation status and navigate to view for installation progress (status will be received when progress will finish).
2. navigate to view where I will by updating installation progress
   using javascript whenever I get callback from server with info about
   progress
3. when installation finishes (status is returned) pass that status to
   another view

In the example above I have some dummy code-behind, so the status is returned immediately, but that has no impact on the problem I have.

Currently I can do 1 and 2 and I can call the final view, but I cant pass the status in there because I dont have it on controller anymore and TempData are not reliable for this (sometimes it is still there, sometimes it is not).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> When it calls "CompletedStatus" action on the controller, variable
>   "status" on the controller is null (the instance set previously is not
>   there?
>
> How do I ensure that its value will persist?
>
> **`private InstallationStatus status = null;`**

It won't unless it's a static value and that would be a very **bad** thing to do. Remember that variable values (private members' values) are only scoped within the http request. If you do another request then that's a totally whole new scope for your private variables.

> I tried using TempData to store it but since there can be more than
>   one step between storing it and retrieving it TempData proved
>   unreliable.

That's because `TempData` will not have the value you expect it to have once you do another request. One good example of using this `TempData` is when you want to pass/move some values between a POST and GET, that is when you do a POST and do a redirect. TempData does not fit your case.

Now for a possible solution to your scenario, a good question is: is the installation process called once? Is it unique per user? If it is, which I highly suspect it is, then you need to **uniquely** identify each request. You can simply use a `GUID` to identify each request. Save that into your database (better than saving in a session) along with some other information like the status of the installation. Pass that guid back to your client and let them pass it back to the controller and retrieve an update on the status of the installation.

Comment: You are right about installation process called only once (providing it wont end up in error, but there is always maximum one running). As a matter of fact, there is only one in total at this point (this is action performed by SuperAdmin when starting up application for the first time). Client doesnt have any database of its own - it communicates only via webservice. And at this very point webservice has no DB either - "Install" method actually triggers creation of main database for whole application. So I have no "external" storage where I could place my status to make it persistent...